# how to use log4j2 properties inside mulesoft expression component

Tags: java, logging, mule

we use logging heavily in most of the application using the log component inside mule flows. But when I use expression component and manipulate payload according to destination system sometimes I need to validate data for that always I need to write system.out.println inside expression component. Is there any way we can invoke or use log4j2 properties like we do inside java component.

Here is the sample code I am looking for

```
//mulesoft payload
additionalfields = payload.additionalfields;
if(org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils.isEmpty(additionalfields))
{
    //System.out.println("we have no data "+additionalfields);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy log like `log.info("we have no data "+additionalfields)`

or use logger like

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("")
logger.info ("we have no data "+additionalfields)
logger.debug("we have no data "+additionalfields)
```

Hope this helps.